# JavaScript parseInt incorrect conversion

Tags: javascript, parseint

Consider:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input Id="1"></input>
        <input Id="2"></input>
        <button Id="3"onclick="add()">Add</button>
        <script>
            function add()
            {
                var num1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
                var val1 = parseInt(num1);
                var num2 = document.getElementById("2").value
                var val2 = parseInt(num2);
                var val3 = val1 + val2;
                var x = +num1 + +num2;

                alert(val3);
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to add two numbers in JavaScript. But when I am providing '11111111111111111' to a textbox, parseInt is converting it into 11111111111111112 instead of 11111111111111111. Why is it doing this?

I have tried all techniques. I first converted var to string and parsed it into int then added, used different radix with parseInt, but I still get nothing.

I also noted that when I am providing 16 1's to it, it's working fine, but with 17 1's it's doing this.

Comment: The parseInt correct format is with radix. i.e `parseInt(value, 10)`. Here radix is `10` for decimal numbers. By default, some browsers assume the radix to be octal i.e `8`. read more [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description).

Comment: I have tried it but still its giving same result i.e 11111111111111112

Comment: @Mr_Green Some browsers do *not* assume the radix to be octal, *unless* the string starts with 0, which is not the case here. And octal  11111111111111111 is certainly not 11111111111111112.

Comment: @rao don't use parseInt. just try this once: `var val3 = val1 - - val2; var x = num1 - - num2;`

Comment: @Mr_Green no, `+'11111111111111111' + 0` (implicit `parseInt` using `+`) also gives `11111111111111112` (in, Chrome at least).

Comment: @pawel sorry, I edited it.

Comment: @Mr_Green without using parseInt and adding like var val3 = num1 + + num2 . answer is 1111111111111111111111111111111112. which is wrong also :(

Comment: @Mr_Green You can't get around the loss of precision, no matter what arithmetics you apply to the numbers. Note that `11111111111111111 === 11111111111111112  // true`. Try to test your "solutions" before posting them...

Comment: @Juhana yup.. sorry for wrong information. thanks for correct information :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JavaScript numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) are [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) doubles which have 15-17 significant digits precision.

In your case the `11111111111111111` number has 17 digits which causes the observed issues.